# Cannot install SDL using mingw/msys

Tags: windows-7, mingw, configure, msys

I don't know whether this is actually an SDL issue or just me not knowing how to build packages from msys/mingw. What I have done thus far:

1. downloaded latest `mingw-get-inst.exe` from sourceforge and ran it. This installed a `C:\MinGW\` directory with msys inside. This brought me to my first bit of confusion. When I opened the mingw shell, rather than bringing me to my `/home/` directory as I expected ( I have used mingw before and remember this being weird ) it placed me in `/c/Users/me/`.
2. I figured that this must be my home directory and put the extracted `SDL-1.2.15/` in this location.
3. I then ran:

   ```
   cd SDL-1.2.15
   ./configure --help
   ```

   but received `sh: ./configure: No such file or directory`.
4. I then created a `/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/` directory, set that as the HOME environment variable, moved the SDL folder into it and tried to configure again with the same result.

There are a few things I really dont understand about installing packages that I hope someone can clear up. I have installed a few before and the `./configure; make; make install;` seems to be a common procedure. I know msys provides the functionality for `make`, but is `configure` a file that is supposed to be included in each package? If so, why is it not in the SDL package/how do configure it?

I have been following instructions from [here](http://blog.pantokrator.net/2006/08/08/setting-up-msysmingw-build-system-for-compiling-sdlopengl-applications/) and they seem to have worked for others in the comments. The bottom-most comment tells that `mingw-get-inst` works, though I did try it both ways.

I have a feeling my lack of msys/mingw knowledge is my problem.

I am on windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you describe and I got SDL, SDL_image and SDL_ttf working after some research.

It seems that the *configure* file exists only in the source code packages. I found that out after I downloaded the SDL_image source. So, the problem probably lies in that the *configure* file comes only in the source packages.

However, I'm having other problems so I'm not sure this has fixed it for me, but it seems like it should.